# Check the render method of 'App' it wont display

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I am getting this error:** I could really use some help

Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

This is my code below for
**Index.js**

```
import React from 'react'; 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import "./App.css";
import Header from './components/Header';
import Users from "./components/users.css";



function App() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
         <Header />
         <Users />
      </div>
    );
  }

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to import a component named `Users`, but are referencing a CSS file instead. Change your `import Users` line to reflect that actual path to the `Users` component.